# Java BigInteger source code performance benchmark

Tags: java, performance, math, benchmarking, biginteger

I'm trying to figure out why a benchmark of Java's BigInteger multiplication is consistently 3x faster than using an instance from BigInteger.java source code copied over to my project.  Using jmh to run the benchmark.  Here is an example output, note that addition runs about the same.

```
Benchmark                                 Mode  Cnt       Score       Error  Units
BenchmarkTest.javaBigInteger_add         thrpt    5  856062.338 � 34040.923  ops/s
BenchmarkTest.sourceBigInteger_add       thrpt    5  842421.746 � 39630.112  ops/s
BenchmarkTest.javaBigInteger_multiply    thrpt    5  525649.635 � 15271.083  ops/s
BenchmarkTest.sourceBigInteger_multiply  thrpt    5  133944.766 �  1832.857  ops/s
```

Reason I am doing this is in an attempt to port part of this to Kotlin I noticed the benchmarks were a bit slower.  To see if it was related to Kotlin I removed that from the picture and did everything in pure java with the exact same results.  Why would this benchmark vary so much if the source code/algorithms are exactly the same?

Project with this code: https://github.com/asheragy/BigInteger-Benchmark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some, maybe even most, JVMs have a number of intrinsic functions that are used instead of the Java code for various computationally intensive operations. More details can be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912510). One of these intrinsics, `multiplyToLen`, deals specifically with `BigInteger` multiplication.

After disabling the usage of this intrinsic function by changing the `jmh` configuration in the `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
jmh {
    warmupIterations = 2 
    iterations = 5 
    fork = 1 
    jvmArgsPrepend = ['-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions', '-XX:-UseMultiplyToLenIntrinsic']
}
```

I'm getting the following multiplication benchmark results on OpenJDK 11 (`JDK 11.0.11, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.11+8-jvmci-21.1-b05`) on an x86-64 architecture:

```
Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt       Score      Error  Units
BenchmarkTest.javaBigInteger    thrpt    5  107476.070 ± 8059.020  ops/s
BenchmarkTest.sourceBigInteger  thrpt    5  108011.737 ± 7105.221  ops/s
```

This almost completely closes the gap between both implementations.

There might be other configuration options that play a smaller role, but I think in general the answer will be that there are various compiler/runtime optimizations in place for standard JDK classes that are not applied to custom implementations.

Comment: Thanks that looks like the answer I was looking for.  Does this mean its impossible to implement your own algorithm that has similar speed to the built in implementation?  At least with this jvm arg I can benchmark to make sure its at close as I can possibly do.